# parsing json not working

Tags: javascript, json

I am new to JSON and I used json_encode to create a JSON object that looks like this

```
[{
      "timestamp": "12\/16\/2013 0:00",
      "curr_property": "7211",
      "curr_property_cost": "123",
      "day_property": "48",
      "day_property_cost": "281",
      "curr_solar_generating": "4958",
      "curr_solar_export": "0",
      "day_solar_generated": "33",
      "day_solar_export": "0",
      "curr_chan1": "1964",
      "curr_chan2": "4958",
      "curr_chan3": "289",
      "day_chan1": "13",
      "day_chan2": "33",
      "day_chan3": "1"
  }, {
      "timestamp": "12\/16\/2013 0:00",
      "curr_property": "7179",
      "curr_property_cost": "123",
      "day_property": "72",
      "day_property_cost": "281",
      "curr_solar_generating": "4926",
      "curr_solar_export": "0",
      "day_solar_generated": "49",
      "day_solar_export": "0",
      "curr_chan1": "1980",
      "curr_chan2": "4926",
      "curr_chan3": "273",
      "day_chan1": "19",
      "day_chan2": "49",
      "day_chan3": "2"
  }, {
      "timestamp": "12\/16\/2013 0:00",
      "curr_property": "9627",
      "curr_property_cost": "165",
      "day_property": "104",
      "day_property_cost": "282",
      "curr_solar_generating": "4749",
      "curr_solar_export": "0",
      "day_solar_generated": "65",
      "day_solar_export": "0",
      "curr_chan1": "1980",
      "curr_chan2": "4749",
      "curr_chan3": "2898",
      "day_chan1": "26",
      "day_chan2": "65",
      "day_chan3": "12"
  }, {
      "timestamp": "12\/16\/2013 0:00",
      "curr_property": "9610",
      "curr_property_cost": "165",
      "day_property": "136",
      "day_property_cost": "282",
      "curr_solar_generating": "4781",
      "curr_solar_export": "0",
      "day_solar_generated": "81",
      "day_solar_export": "0",
      "curr_chan1": "1980",
      "curr_chan2": "4781",
      "curr_chan3": "2849",
      "day_chan1": "32",
      "day_chan2": "81",
      "day_chan3": "21"
  }, {
      "timestamp": "12\/16\/2013 0:01",
      "curr_property": "9691",
      "curr_property_cost": "166",
      "day_property": "168",
      "day_property_cost": "283",
      "curr_solar_generating": "4797",
      "curr_solar_export": "0",
      "day_solar_generated": "97",
      "day_solar_export": "0",
      "curr_chan1": "1996",
      "curr_chan2": "4797",
      "curr_chan3": "2898",
      "day_chan1": "39",
      "day_chan2": "97",
      "day_chan3": "31"
  }, {
      "timestamp": "12\/16\/2013 0:01",
      "curr_property": "7034",
      "curr_property_cost": "120",
      "day_property": "191",
      "day_property_cost": "283",
      "curr_solar_generating": "4781",
      "curr_solar_export": "0",
      "day_solar_generated": "113",
      "day_solar_export": "0",
      "curr_chan1": "1980",
      "curr_chan2": "4781",
      "curr_chan3": "273",
      "day_chan1": "46",
      "day_chan2": "113",
      "day_chan3": "32"
}]
```

I have tried to parse the data using the script below

```
$(document).ready(
        function() {
            var jsonData = JSON.parse("<?php echo $jsondata; ?>");  
            console.log(jsonData.timestamp[0]);             

    });
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong here. I do know that an has a length of 0 by default in javascript, so how do I get the value? BTW var_dump on the $jsondata gives out the data

Comment: I think you have your quotes wrong. Replace with single quotes - `var jsonData = JSON.parse('<?php echo $jsondata; ?>');` as the JSON string contains double quotes within.

Comment: now I get a Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined Using "" is the correct way from what I have read so far.

Comment: validate your json data in http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: It validates @KarthickKumarGanesh

Comment: It should be jsonData[0].timestamp, not jsonData.timestamp[0]

Comment: You should also have a look at [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `console.log(jsonData.timestamp[0]);` which basically means, inside `jsonData` find property timestamp which is an array and get the first index.

But jsonData is the array, not timestamp. You should probably go with something like `console.log(jsonData[0].timestamp);`

Comment: I didn't know this part so thanks a lot, will select it as the right answer after 2 minutes

Comment: @Bazinga777: I wonder how this works for you, given that `var jsonData = JSON.parse("<?php echo $jsondata; ?>");` should produce invalid JavaScript.

Comment: I replaced "" with ''

Comment: $(document).ready(
   function() {
    var jsonData = <?php echo $jsondata; ?>; 
    console.log(jsonData[0].timestamp);    
       
  }); also worked

Comment: @Bazinga777: Using `'` instead of `"` will work as long as your data won't contain any `'`. It looks like your data is mostly numerical, so you will be fine for now. Note though that `var jsonData = <?php echo $jsondata; ?>;` is still the superior solution.

Answer (score 6):

Your JSON data includes `"` characters. You are trying to inject it into a JavaScript string literal that is delimited with `"` but you aren't escaping the `"` characters in the data.

Your JSON also includes new lines, literal new lines are not allowed in JavaScript strings, so you need to replace them with escape sequences (`\n`) too.

That said, JSON is a subset of JavaScript literal syntax, so you don't need to go to the effort of converting a JSON text into a JavaScript string literal and then parsing it, you can simply use the JSON as JavaScript:

```
var data = <?php echo $jsondata; ?>;
```

---

You have another problem. Your JSON data represents an array of objects, not an object that has arrays as property values. You need to access the array *before* the property name: `data[0].timestamp`.

Comment: Okay, what is it with people upvoting this answer and not mine? I was faster on the single quotes and array access answers, but this guy gets the votes because of 288k rep?

Comment: @Cerbrus: No, simply because it's a better answer. Why would use `JSON.parse` if you don't have to? Your solutions isn't even reliable: what happens if the JSON data contains a `'`?

Comment: @Cerbrus If you are doing it for the reps, you are doing it for the wrong reasons man. I am here on S/O for like 4 years. It's a fun place to help out people. No competition.

Comment: @Shouvik: Some recognition for a answer would be nice.
FelixKling: I didn't think about that, that's a fair point.

Comment: I have used that too , now I get a Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined  error. Could it be that the JSONData is so large that the data doesn't exist when I pass it to the javascript But then again I user document.ready. please advise

Comment: @Bazinga777 — Sounds like you haven't dealt with the problem described in the final paragraph of this answer.

Comment: @Bazinga777: *"Could it be that the JSONData is so large that the data doesn't exist"* No, the client receives the complete source before it executes it. This has nothing to do with `document.ready` either.

Comment: @Quentin: No, that rather sounds like `data` is `undefined`, which seems like a different issue.

Comment: @FelixKling — Could be either.

Comment: Thanks, guys. I solved it. I was wrong about using "" but I got my main answer solved by another user. I will upvote for the right suggestions and select the other answer as the right answer.

Comment: @Quentin: Oh right, I didn't notice that the OP had `.timestamp[0]`. My bad!

Answer (score 2):

Try using single quotes here:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse("<?php echo $jsondata; ?>");
```

Replace that with:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse('<?php echo $jsondata; ?>');
```

Because the `$jsondata` contains double quotes (`"`), the string passed to `JSON.parse()` will be broken, resulting in invalid JavaScript.

However, as Quentin answered, the whole `JSON.parse` is unnecessary.
[Like he answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21848687/1835379), use: `var data = <?php echo $jsondata; ?>;`

Also, you're accessing the object incorrectly:

```
jsonData.timestamp[0];
```

Should be:

```
jsonData[0].timestamp;
```

your JSON is a array of timestamp objects, so use the array index `[0]`, first.

Comment: That's not sufficient, the JSON includes new lines too.

Comment: @Quentin: OP used `json_encode`, that should return a valid JSON string without the newlines. I believe that's just a formatting mistake from asking the question.

Comment: Perhaps the pretty print options were used?

Comment: You have my upvote! I hope you keep contributing for more reasons than just votes though! :)

Comment: @Shouvik: It's not the points that are bugging me. It's the way the vote system is sometimes played. Or answers that are absolute bollocks getting a early +1, and people just joining in on that +1 because that answer was the only one with votes at the moment (Which wasn't the case here, the other answer is indeed better)

Comment: @Cerbrus people upvote answers of people they follow blindly because they feel the need to upvote that person. They are expressing `thank-yous` for posts on another answer. The problem is S/O limits the points you can upvote an answer. Anymore and you will have to issue a bounty and award the person from your points. People prefer not to follow that ideology. No point complaining. No system is foolproof.